# Periodicity of $\cos(2n + \theta)$

Tags: periodic

I have to calculate periodicity of `e^j(2n + π/4)`

If `cos2n` is Aperiodic then what is the periodicity of  `cos(2n + π/4)` ?
Please explain in steps for beginner!

Comment: Hi and welcome to dsp.stackexchange.com! Please add some details to your question, for example the exact wording of your assignment. This seems to be a homework question, so you are more likely to receive help, if you show some effort of your own.

Comment: so are you saying that $\cos 2n$ is "aperiodic" or "a periodic"?

Comment: Cos2n is aperiodic!

Comment: What is the meaning of aperiodic? The cosine function is periodic with $T=2\pi$.

Comment: @KrishnaKumarS Changing the phase of an aperiodic signal cannot turn it into periodic.

Comment: @Zacky While $\cos(t)$ is periodic with $T=2\pi$, as you say, the discrete signal $\cos[n]$ is not, since $n$ is required to be an integer.